# How to delete this WindowsApps folder (permission denied with rm even with sudo :( )?

Tags: permissions, windows, rm

I used to use windows on my laptop and then moved ubuntu. While I was using windows, I once moved microsoft store apps to a different partition to save space in C drive and I guess it was saved in "WindowsApps" folder. Now I use Ubuntu and I don't need that folder anymore but can't delete it. If I execute `sudo rm -rf ./WindowsApps` then I get

```
rm: cannot remove './WindowsApps/Microsoft.MinecraftUWP_1.16.20102.0_x64__8wekyb3d8bbwe/data/test/MPThresholds.json': Permission denied
rm: cannot remove './WindowsApps/Microsoft.MinecraftUWP_1.16.20102.0_x64__8wekyb3d8bbwe/UAP.Assets/minecraft/icons': Directory not empty
rm: cannot remove './WindowsApps/Microsoft.MinecraftUWP_1.16.20102.0_x64__8wekyb3d8bbwe/UAP.Win10.Assets/minecraft/icons/Minecraft_3D_Tile.GLB': Permission denied
```

(there were a lot of erros like this, I only copied the last 3)
How do I delete them?

Comment: How are your drives partitioned?  Is the Windows partition mounted read only?

Comment: That was an extra ntfs partition and not read only.

Comment: NTFS does not know any permissions by default. Check the (surrogate) permissions the drive was mounted with:  $ ls -al

Comment: Have a look at: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/206594/why-cant-i-delete-this-file-as-root

Comment: Have that drive checked by a Windows system so it is clean, then try again. Alternatively, and better, reformat that drive to a linux file system if you cannot use it anymore with Windows.